# How to import module from current non-default directory

Tags: python, import, module

I'm using Python 2.7. I'm rather new to the python langauge. I have two python modules - "Trailcrest.py" and "Glyph.py", both in the same folder, but not in the Python27 folder.

I need to import "Trailcrest.py" into "Glyph.py", but I am getting the message that "no such module exists".

Additionally, whatever means I use to import the module needs to not be dependent on a solid-state path. This program is cross-platform, and the path can be changed depending on the user's preferences. However, these two modules will always be in the same folder together.

How do I do this?

Comment: So then how are you importing Glyph.py?

Comment: I'm running Glyph.py in shell, not importing it. I need to import "Trailcrest.py" INTO Glyph.py.

Comment: Then the directory should already be in `sys.path`. Wait... don't tell me that you're trying to import `Trailcrest.py` instead of `Trailcrest`...

Comment: I've tried both. Neither works. And some code would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have `Trailcrest.py` and `Glyph.py` in the same folder, importing one into the other is as simple as:

```
import Trailcrest
import Glyph
```

If this does not work, there seems to be something wrong with your Python setup.  You might want to check what's in `sys.path`.

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

Comment: Ah HAH! The path was right, by Trailcrest was saved as TrailcrestCore. Der >.<

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate a bit on Ferdinand Beyer's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576351/how-to-import-module-from-current-non-default-directory/6576445#6576445), `sys.path` is a list of file locations that the default module importer checks.  Some, though not all installations of python will add the current directory or the directory of the `__main__` module to the path.  To make sure that the paths relative to a given module are importable in that module, do something like this:

```
import os.path, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

But something like that shouldn't ever make it into a "production" product.  Instead, use something like `distutils` to install the module's package into the python site-packages directory.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be achieved using the environment variable `PYTHONPATH` which also influences Python's search path. This can be done in a shell script so that the Python files do not need to be altered. If you want it to import from the current working directory use the `.` notation in bash:

```
export PYTHONPATH=.
python python_prog.py
```